# How do you access req.body.title of a postman request with the body set to raw data

Tags: javascript, express, postman, postman-collection-runner

Here is the raw data that I am using. It is set to Text by default.

```
{  
   "title":"New Course",
   "description":"My course description",
   "user":{  
      "_id":"57029ed4795118be119cc437"
   },
   "steps":[  
      {  
         "title":"Step 1",
         "description":"My First Step"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am receiving the data in my route with:

```
if (req.body.title && req.body.description) {
    //  something good
} else {
    //  bad news bears
}
```

But it is returning false for some reason. And the values are undefined.

Comment: Do you think your `if` statement is written correct way? what is this `if (req.body.title, req.body.description)` ?

Comment: What is `req.body` ? Are you using `bodyParser.json()` ?

Comment: Try to set the data type to `json` instead of Text

Comment: Did you add any header? `Content-Type`? Those are telling your server what is arriving.

Comment: How does the client receive response from `if`?

Comment: I am using bodyParser.json(), That is just the beginning of the if statement I will update. I set data type to json but I get the error: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". I did add a auth header but no Content-Type header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment  get the `error: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".` This error comes only if you are parsing data which is already JSON object.

Please try below steps to debug your problem, hope this will help :)

1. Set `content-type` header to `application/json` in POSTMAN before sending request to server
2. In above code put `console.log(req.body)` before if condition if `(req.body.title && req.body.description)` and verify what type of data you are getting on server side
3. If body is object you can access its properties, if body is string then you need to parse it to JSON using `JSON.parse(req.body)`